# Grails: With the datasources plugin, having trouble connecting domain classes across different datasources

Tags: java, hibernate, grails

I'm using the datasources pluging for Grails described here: http://burtbeckwith.com/blog/?p=70

I'm connecting to 2 MySQL database schemas on the same server: my_schema_1 and my_schema_2. Most of the data I need comes from my_schema_1, but one of its tables contains a column that references one of the tables in my_schema_2.

Here are my datasource definitions in my Datasources.groovy file (simplified):

```
datasources = {
    datasource(name: 'my_schema_1') {
        domainClasses([Question, Answer])
        driverClassName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
        url('jdbc:mysql://test.myserver.com/my_schema_1')
        username('***')
        password('***')
    }

    datasource(name: 'my_schema_2') {
        domainClasses([Genre])
        driverClassName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
        url('jdbc:mysql://test.myserver.com/my_schema_2')
        username('***')
        password('***')
    }
}
```

Here are my 3 class definitions:

```
class Question {
    String text
    Answer answer
    Genre genre
}

class Answer {
    String text
}

class Genre {
    String name
}
```

Whenever I try to perform a criteria query on the Question class, I get the following mapping exception:

```
An association from the table question refers to an unmapped class: Genre
```

If I comment out the genre property in the Question class, everything works fine. If I perform a criteria query on the Genre class itself,
everything works fine. There just seems to be a problem joining the 2 classes across schemas. (Of course, it's also very possible I missed
something or did something incorrectly.)

Am I doing something wrong or is this a limitation of the datasources plugin? And, if this is a limitation of the plugin, what alternatives could I use to achieve what I need?

Any help/suggestions are much appreciated.

Thanks,

B.J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simpler solution since the databases are on the same server.

I simply define one datasource as follows (without specifying a database):

```
datasources = {
    datasource(name: 'my_schemas') {
        domainClasses([Question, Answer, Genre])
        driverClassName('com.mysql.jdbc.Driver')
        url('jdbc:mysql://test.myserver.com')
        username('***')
        password('***')
    }
}
```

Then I specify the database in my domain classes' mapping sections:

```
class Question {
    String text
    Answer answer
    Genre genre

    static mapping = {
        table 'my_schema_1.question'
    }
}

class Answer {
    String text

    static mapping = {
        table 'my_schema_1.answer'
    }
}

class Genre {
    String name

    static mapping = {
        table 'my_schema_2.genre'
    }
}
```

Again, this only works because the 2 databases are on the same server, and they use the same username/password.

Answer (score 3):

The datasources plugin only supports weak-references between databases. This means you will need to manage the integrity of the associations yourself. The best way to accomplish this is to implement a service that is capable of querying both domain instances and providing you with the composite domain instance.

The link you referenced notes this towards the bottom of the entry. Also, here is the [same question](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Datasources-Plugin-M-N-Relationship-Tables-are-in-Different-Databases-td3687544.html) posed (and answered) on the grails mailing lists.

Comment: Thanks, Joshua, for your response. I'll make sure to work on my reading comprehension skills before I post next time ;). Are you saying that the only way to accomplish what I want is to query both tables independently and join them myself?

Comment: That is correct. You could in fact place the logic of querying the child instances within the Domain class for the parent instance. However, using a service instead seems like the easier route.